Why does a `UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(...)))` not yield a list of unique values?
I was trying to help solving this question.
My proposal was based on the idea to get unique identifiers, using the Unique() worksheet function.
So, in cell "B1" I put the value "1,2,3,4,5".
In cell "B2" I put the value "2,3,4,5,6".
Using the formula =UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;B1;B2);",")), I was hoping to get a list of unique identifiers, but this did not work out.
I have written this as an answer (formulating an approach, and hoping somebody would react in a comment), but as another answer has already been accepted, I fear the question in my answer will not be regarded anymore, and I'm really curious: why is my formula not working? (I did use formula auditing and it seems that it's really the Unique() worksheet function, causing the problem. I have also tried sorting the entries first, but as sorting seems not to work, also that seems not to be a solution)
Ok, I have finally found a solution: apparently the whole thing needs a conversion into columns in order to make it work:
=UNIQUE(SORT(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;B1:B2);",")))

Result : "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6" => NOK
=TOROW(UNIQUE(SORT(TOCOL(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;B1:B2);",")))))

Result : "1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6" => OK
Is this a bug? Are there any plans to solve this issue?

UNIQUE has optional parameter [by_col]. Set it to TRUE and that's it :) =UNIQUE(SORT(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;B1:B2);","));TRUE)

@user11222393: indeed, this is also what Excellor already mentioned. However, I am expecting a similar parameter in the Sort() function, which seems not to work.

Could you be more specific on SORT problem? =SORT(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;B1:B2);",");;;TRUE) seems to work as intended

@user11222393: sorry, you are right. Apparently I made a typo.

Try this:
=UNIQUE(SORT(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;B1:B2);","));TRUE)

Like said in the comments, you can even drop the SORT():
=UNIQUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;B1:B2);",");TRUE)

Check the UNIQUE arguments list to see why that TRUE matters.

EDIT: if you want to actually use your outputted numbers as actual numbers, you have to add in VALUE() as such:
=UNIQUE(VALUE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;B1:B2);","));TRUE)

Otherwise the output will give numbers formatted as TEXT.

Alternatively, you can use TRANSPOSE instead of TOCOL and TOROW, but that only works if you use only one row output (so in this case it would work), can even double transpose to return a row again.
=TRANSPOSE(UNIQUE(TRANSPOSE(TEXTSPLIT(TEXTJOIN(",";TRUE;A10;A11);","))))


I understand now, thanks. But let's be honest: this explains how Unique() can work with a single row instead of with a single column, and you might even drop the SORT() in your answer, It will still work. But what about that SORT() then? Also the SORT() function has a to_col parameter, but putting this to TRUE or FALSE does not change anything.

@Dominique yeah you can drop the SORT() ; whenever I'm unsure about a formula/argument, I make comparisons with random data; also, since you're creating TEXT I'm not sure the sort even does anything, but I'll have to test that out myself too.

The SORT() is needed if you want them in order and even text carries a value to sort them by so that's no problem. Just don't forget the TRUE for the bycol argument in the sort. As for your newest edit for the values, you can also multiply by 1 and they become numbers as well.

Apparently, I was wrong saying there's an error in the Sort() function (I must have made a typo). Everything is working fine now.

@Dominique if you just copied the formula there probably was a delimter error (I fixed it, didn't use the same one throughout the answer).
